# User input if statements in Java not working

Tags: java, if-statement

I am using scanner to take user input.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Int choice = scanner.nextInt();

if(choice==1) {
    System.out.println(" you chosed number 1!")
}

if(choice==2) {
    System.out.println(" you chosed number 2!")
}

if(choice==3) {
    System.out.println(" you chosed number 3!")
}

if(choice==q) {
    System.out.println("the game will end now!");
}
```

So when you enter the game you have a menu that pops up. You can chose between 1, 2, 3 or q. If you press any of the numbers the game will take you to those sections.
But if you press q the game will end.

I don't know how to fix so that I can enter q and game ends.

Comment: First of all, integer types start with a lowercase i. I'd also suggest chaining if statements together. You can quit with `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Hint: if you want the user to enter 'q', you're not really asking them to enter an integer.

Comment: nextInt() will ignore characters

Comment: i understand that i cant use scanner.nextInt if i want to be able to press q, in the if statements. but what else can i do?

Comment: what is chaining if statements?. how do i solve this problem

Comment: For chaining, see @AndrewL.'s answer and how he uses  `else if`

Comment: you program will and in all cases if you do not have a Loop around the scanner and if else parts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got some typos, and your logic is incorrect. You are missing quite a lot of semicolons, they end a statement. When will an int become a char? The char isn't enclosed it in quotes. Use `next` to get a string version. Use `.equals()` to check strings.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String choice = scanner.next();

if(choice.equals("1")) {
    System.out.println(" you chose number 1!");
} else if(choice.equals("2")) {
    System.out.println(" you chose number 2!");
} else if(choice.equals("3")) {
    System.out.println(" you chose number 3!");
} else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    System.out.println("the game will end now!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You can also parse as an integer and compare using `==`.

The above code will get the user input as a string. Then it will check if it equals 1, 2, 3, or q and then executes lines accordingly. Q is checked and case is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Since commands are characters, use `nextByte` instead of `nextInt`. Use `switch`-`case` instead of `if`-`else` to simplify your code. [Convert your byte into char](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/java-best-practices-char-to-byte-and.html) and use it for your `switch`, the cases will be '1' '2' '3' and 'q'. If you want the game to continue until `'q'` wrap a `while` around your `switch`-`case` with the end sign of 'q'. Since this is a homework most probably, I do not write the source-code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get nextInt() from scanner, coz lateral will be ignored.
Also to prevent many if/else u can use switch/case.
scanner.next() will return some string, after that we get for each case and compare that string with string in case.
Add break to stop walking in cases.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    switch (scanner.next()) {
        case "q" : System.exit(0);
        case "1" :
            System.out.println("1");
            break;

        //...

        case "7" :
            System.out.print("7");
            break;
        default: System.out.print("Try one more time");
    }
```

If scanner.next != any cases u return message from "default".

Comment: Code without explanation helps no one! Please add one to better the answer

Answer (score -1):

When compairing strings, you can't simply use ==.
In that case you need to use choice.equals("q")

Comment: `choice` is an `int`. It can not be dereferenced.

Comment: @Berger Yes there is; but no string will be read withscanner.nextInt()...